# in Germany, who appoints Prosecutor

Tags: comparative-law

in Germany who and how appoints Prosecutors?

ps.
I am looking at http://iate.europa.eu/'s translations, with entry 'EN Prosecutor':

EN public prosecutor
DE Leitender Oberstaatsanwalt
FR procureur de la République
IT procuratore della Repubblica

EN public prosecutor's office
DE Staatsanwaltschaft
FR parquet / ministère public
IT procura / pubblico ministero

Comments on translations are welcome too.

Comment: In Germany every officer in the public prosecutor's office is a "*Staatsanwalt*" and the person responsible for the prosecution in a given area/jurisdiction is the “*Leitender Oberstaatsanwalt*". By contrast, in most US states, the "district attorney" is the boss and everybody else is an "assistant DA" (in the federal system: "US attorney" and "assistant US attorneys"). Same thing in France with the "*procureur de la République*" and his or her "*subsituts*". Which one are you interested in?

Comment: @Relaxed. I would say both, just to understand who is really in charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search shows a quote from *Public Prosecutors in the United States and Europe: A Comparative Analysis*, by G. Gilliéron:

> In Germany, the federal prosecutor general and federal prosecutors are appointed by the President of Germany upon proposal of the Minister of Justice and with the consent of the legislative chamber (*Bundesrat*). State prosecutors are appointed by the State Minister of Justice.

As an aside, I don't agree with the Italian translation of the term "public prosecutor's office". "Procura" is correct, but "Pubblico Ministero" is not. In fact, even if the Italian word "ministero" usually refers to an office (as opposite to "Ministro" i.e. Minister), "Pubblico Ministero" is not the name of the office, which is actually "ufficio del Pubblico Ministero".

Comment: I am not sure 100%, but I do think that _Procuratore_ and _Pubblico Ministero_ are synonymous terms, so _Procura_ is the same as _Ufficio del PM_ too. You are right to sort out Office from Official, although I  pretty sure that italians say just _Pubblico Ministero_ for the office too.

Comment: @darwin, do you  know whether Germany has something like italian _Magistratura_?

Comment: It doesn't look to me like the translation is intending to provide the proper name of an Italian office; it looks rather like it's providing the generic Italian term to denote a "public prosecutor's office" in any country.

Comment: @phoog Perhaps you're right. However, as a native speaker, I would feel slightly confused by someone using the term "pubblico ministero" to denote an office (even if it wouldn't refer to the specific, Italian one), although I would understand its meaning in a given context. Moreover, I don't quite see why the same reasoning isn't applied to the English term, should someone need to translate the word "Staatsanwaltschaft". After all, "public prosecutor's office" is literally equivalent to "ufficio del pubblico ministero".